# fixed-width box inside section with table of contents and thumbnails

Tags: beamer

I'd like to insert a fixed-width box inside a section and to have it properly displayed in the table of contents (see the thumbnails in the screenshot).

In the MWE below I have sucesfully created the box inside the main beamer frame, but it doesn't display as expected inside the thumbnail.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\newcommand{\PART}[1]{\protect\makebox[20pt][l]{#1}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\section{\PART{I.}Part One}

\begin{frame}
\PART{I.} Part One.
\end{frame}

\section{\PART{II.} Part Two}

\begin{frame}
\PART{II.} Part Two.
\end{frame}

\section{\PART{III.}  Part Three}

\begin{frame}
\PART{III.} Part Three.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The purpose of the fixed-width box is to have a consistent alignment of the text immediately following the numbering `I.`, `II.`, `III.`, etc..

I'm not looking for automatic numbering, as these `\PART`s are designed to indicate pauses in the presentation and other `sections` will be inserted in between them.

**EDIT**: While the `[20pt][l]` part doesn't get printed inside a `\tableofcontents`, the alignment is not preserved, so my objective is not achieved there either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf viewers I tested use a fixed width font for the bookmarks. Therefore the following manual hack could be used to align them:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\newcommand{\PART}[2]{\texorpdfstring{\protect\makebox[20pt][l]{#1}\ignorespaces}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\section{\PART{I.}{I.\space\space\space}Part One}

\begin{frame}
\PART{I.}{} Part One.
\end{frame}

\section{\PART{II.}{II.\space\space}Part Two}

\begin{frame}
\PART{II.}{} Part Two.
\end{frame}

\section{\PART{III.}{III.\space}Part Three}

\begin{frame}
\PART{III.}{} Part Three.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work with my beamer workflow. Because I have many extra packages, it's probably caused by some interference from some package and/or font. I get that only one ``\space`` is active, the other spaces are gobbled up, so that the spacing in the table of contents thumbnails is not as desired. On the positive side, spacing works fine in the ``\tableofcontents``. With your experience, do you have suggestions about where I should look for potential interference? Any popular package you can think of that might gobble the spaces? Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT There are so many possible reasons why this could break, hard to diagnose. Can you try to trim your code down to a MWE? Maybe you could also ask a question including all your requirements about how the toc should look like. It would probably safer to fix the alignment via adjusting the necessary templates for the toc instead of trying to hack the alignment in the section titles, but to do this I would need to know how normal sections should look like and what's  the purpose of your parts is.

Comment: Thanks Sam! Don't worry, I'll live with the weird alignment, it's not bad. Creating a MWE at this time feels overwhelming! What with deadlines and distractions caused by the Paris open. I'll take your advice and create a MWE in a couple of weeks when deadlines are either beaten or irrelevant. Thanks!